# how to buy a film dubbing stage

Tags: dubbing-stage

who are the best manufacturers of dubbing stages.

please introduce me the brands which are the leaders in this industry.

Comment: Consoles? I'm not familiar with this stuff too much but I know a couple names. There's AMS Neve, Harrison, Solid State Logic, Avid's Icon & System 5 and I'm not to sure about this one but Eurodesk?.

Comment: Which country are you based in?

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong but I'd be guessing most people who want to 'buy' a dubbing stage spend many, many months (& maybe even years) researching & taking advice from the people who will actually be operating their dub stage ie **very experienced re-recording mixers**
You're talking about a multi-million dollar investment, which isn't the kind of thing left to the random advice from strangers on online forums....

Comment: sorry if I am stating the obvious.... but you know its not about brand names right?

Comment: you must be joking tim. i only buy brand name dub stages.

Answer (score 0):

http://philipnewell.net/

http://www.munro.co.uk/

These guys design great rooms. I've been in a couple of their stages and they're pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for Munro - I think they kitted out dubbing stage at NFTS, they did a great job

Answer (score 0):

Any suggestions would have to be based on budget and location.
Building a dub stage is not a job done via the Internet. The accousticcian will have to be on site a number of times.
The budget will limit your choice of designers if you have to choose locally or if you can afford to choose globally.
Ive been arund building two stages. It's not easy nor cheap.